# Can I promote the Coursera team plan to my boss?

Tags: team, learning

I have learned for about a year on Coursera outside working hours, and I think the courses may also benefit my teammates. Recently I found the platform provides a [team plan](https://www.coursera.org/business/teams), so I wonder if I can recommend my colleagues learn from the same materials?

My boss knows that I have spent lots of money on online learning (SCPD and Coursera mainly) but he never mentions if I can apply for reimbursement and I've never heard of any tuition assistance programs in my company. I wonder if I can recommend the plan to my boss. For one thing, it would save me some money, and it's not expensive; for another, it's good for the team to support each other both for the courses and for the projects.

Comment: Which question? Want reimbursement? Want your colleagues forced to do it? Do you get a discount for bringing new business?

Comment: @SolarMike I would get a discount. Yes, I want reimbursement, if possible.

Comment: Keep in mind, companies don't care if it benefits teammates, it has to benefit the business.

Comment: If your company has a training/learning representative in HR, you can also start there. These often come with their own budget which makes this an easier sell.

Comment: Is “can I” really the question you want to ask (yes, of course you “can.”).  Do you mean to ask how to effectively sell the team plan to him, or just how to most effectively get reimbursed for your own education, or...?

Answer (score 2):

You can, however be prepared that any action you took before he okayed it, is not very likely to be reimbursed.

Going forward, you might be able to get your boss to start paying for the courses. But make sure you are on the same page there. Don’t assume, or you’ll be disappointed.